# Why my svg picture is truncated at the bottom when embedded in html

Tags: html, css, svg

my svg is just text over a circke with full screen rectangle

svg

```
<svg version="1.1"
 baseProfile="full"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>

<circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green"/>

<text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">Hello SVG</text>

</svg>
```

When in img src it is arbitriraly truncated at the bottom why ? How to fix this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="hello.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `width`, `height` and `viewPort` attributes of `svg`.

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="300" height="200" viewPort="0 0 300 200" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" />
  <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">Hello SVG</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified any size for the `<img>` or `<svg>` so the browser is choosing the default size for indeterminate sized objects, which is 300x150.  So your circle will get cut off at the bottom.  The solution, as chipChocolate has already pointed out, is to give one or the other an appropriate size.